# How to run nginx master process with different user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, passenger

A/c to http://wiki.nginx.org/CoreModule#user

master process used to run with root user, is it possible to run nginx mater process with different user?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Using the `user` directive will change the uid anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is possible to run the nginx master process with a different user by just running the init script as non root (i.e. `/etc/init.d/nginx start`).

If this is really what you want to do, you will need to ensure the log and pid directories (usually `/var/log/nginx` & `/var/run/nginx.pid`) are writable for that user, and all your `listen` calls are for ports greater than 1024 (because binding to ports <=1024 requires root privileges).

In most situations however, you run the nginx master process as root and specify the `user` directive so that nginx workers processes run as that user.

Comment: Could you be more precise on _specify the `user` directive so that nginx workers processes run as that user._? Can you set `user` in each `.conf` which are located in separate folder fof the  _virtual hosts_, on per sub domain? My intention is to run the proxied servers for my sub domains under unique user accounts.